# Running a spring batch job multiple times

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have created a spring batch job with spring boot using below tutorial:

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/
```

The job is reading a file and writing to a database as expected.

However, now I have a use case to run this job multiple times.

I have an `ArrayList` of parameters.

What changes should I do to the job so that I can run the job the number of times the size of my `ArrayList` ?

Comment: Have the `read()` method of your `ItemReader`, read one file  of your list at a time , until it reaches the end of the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can kickstart your batch job manually like this

```
@Component
Class Someclass{
  ...............
     @Autowired
     private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
     @Autowired
     private Job job;  

     public void someFunction(){
       jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());  
   }
}
```

Only thing is you cannot restart a batch job if it is already completed, It throws an error saying the status is COMPLETED. For this to work you have to set `allowStartIfComplete` property to true. This has to be done in your batch step configuration,  something like this

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the job with empty parameters:

```
jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
```

If you already have parameters and they aren't empty try this work around:

```
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addLong("id", 500L)
            .addDate("startedAt", new Date())
            .toJobParameters();

jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

added the current date as parameter

Note: it will be a bit tricky to get execution from `JobRepository` by `JobParameters`