# Spring batch should be executed every time in case of any change in the specified directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a business requirement where my spring batch should be auto triggered during any change happened in specific directory.

Currently my Spring batch is being triggered with a cron expression.

Could any one of you guys please help on this ?

Comment: How are the changes made?

Comment: spring batch doesn't have anything inbuilt to poll a directory for changes. You need to use someother frameworks to poll the directoy, and then you can trigger the job

Comment: U mean directory changes?If so any file being created newly over here

Comment: pvpkiran,how I can trigger the job,If i use watch service

Comment: ya, any file added, deleted or edited

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326897/running-a-spring-batch-job-multiple-times/44327033#44327033

Comment: Do you have a directory on windows or linux?

Comment: yeah. you should look into Spring Integration then. It has already `integration` (pun intended) with spring batch